# Close Popup Window by Clicking on Parent onfocus

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I'm trying to close a popup that is created by clicking on a link within the parent window, by clicking back on the parent window. The function that controls this seems to work fine, but will not allow me to click on the links again to open another popup. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

The code is listed below. FYI, the code is not that well formatted because it involves numerous hacks for a legacy CMS:

```
 var chkListWindow;

function ChkListPopup(guidNum){
  if(typeof chkListWindow === "null" || typeof chkListWindow === "undefined"){
              //do nothing
       }else{
              chkListWindow.close();
       }
  chkListWindow = window.open('','_blank', 'width = 1050, height = 680, scrollbars=no, titlebar=no, status=no, toolbar=no, location=no, top=0;');
  chkListWindow.document.write(
"<div class='scrollBox' style='width:100%; height:680px; margin:-15px 0 0 -10px; padding:0; border:0; text-align:center;'>"
    +"<div class'scrollContent' style='position:absolute; margin:80px 0 0 75px; width:900px; height:517px; overflow:auto; border:solid 1px #bababa; background-color:#fff'>"
        +"<img src='MediaServer?id="+guidNum+"'>"
    +"</div>"
    +"<div class='bgImg' style='width:1050px; height:680px; position:fixed !important; margin:0; padding:0; border:0; z-index:5;'>"
        +"<img src='MediaServer?id=DCA3205241531B8226B21308001A01E2'>"
    +"</div>"
+"</div>");
}

window.onfocus = function(){
    if(typeof chkListWindow === "null" || typeof chkListWindow === "undefined"){
        //do nothing
    } else {
        chkListWindow.close();
        chkListWindow = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using '=== null' instead of '=== "null"'. The latter is a string and not a null object.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the quotes from both instances of null that had quotes, but I still have the issue of popups not working after the first popup closes.